# Magento Default Pages

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am newly stuyding in Magento.

Could you explain me about, How many default Magento pages are there after completing installation and what are they?

Default Page Like :

```
-> Home Page
-> Login Page
-> Register Page
-> Contact Us
-> Forget Password 
etc..
```

Like that's.

Could you please assist me ..?

Answer (score 0):

In magento 1.9 by default,

About Us

Customer Service

Enable Cookies

Home page

404 Not Found

Privacy Policy

Login page

Checkout page

Cart page

Registration page

Account Dashboard

Account Information

Address Book

My Orders

Search Orders

Billing Agreements

Recurring Profiles

My Product Reviews

My Tags

My Wishlist

My Applications

Newsletter Subscriptions

My Downloadable Products

Search terms

Sitemap

Advanced search

Category page

Product list page

Product view page

Answer (score 0):

#### How to find these pages:

1. Default CMS pages (like "home page" or "privacy policy"): Look at the *CMS > Pages* menu in the admin panel
2. Pages with functionality: Search the source code for classes in `app/code/core/*/*/controllers`, ignore `Adminhtml` directories (those are for the admin panel only), and you'll find all *actions* in the form

   ```
   class Mage_Something_HelloController
   {
       public function worldAction()
       {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

   This would be the action for a URL like `something/hello/world`. You will also find actions that are not used to display pages, but as form actions (i.e. they perform some action and then redirect somewhere else), but you'll probably recognize that (for example `addToCartAction`)

   Also, some actions are used to show content with dynamic URLs, for example `catalog/product/view` - these URLs are usually not opened directly, instead the actions get called by Magentos URL rewrite system if the product URL is opened.